# Does the jQuery .unbind() method only work on jQuery created events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to unbind all event handlers for all elements that are inside a particular container.  Like a DIV.  But those events have been bound/registered not using jQuery.  Some are bound the manual way with `onclick="...."`  or using regular native JavaScript.

But when I do something like this

```
$('#TheDivContainer').find('div,td,tr,tbody,table').unbind();
```

It does not appear to work.  Which leads me to believe that the `.unbind()` only works if the events have been originally bound by jQuery.

Is that true?  Is there another way of unbinding all events from a group of elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right. As in the [API](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/):

> Any handler that has been attached
>   with .bind() can be removed with
>   .unbind().

Answer (score 3):

You could always do this:

```
$('#TheDivContainer').find('div,td,tr,tbody,table')
  .unbind('click')
  .attr('onclick', ''); // edited to change null to ''
```

etc. for all appropriate event types.

Comment: it works for me - see this test page: http://gutfullofbeer.net/unbind.html - you might try calling `attr()` with an empty string as the second parameter instead of a null!

Answer (score 3):

Unbind will only work on jQuery created events as all methods that does this (addEventListener, and attachEvent) requires the both the node, the eventname, **and** the handler as an argument. `bind` takes care of storing these for you..

By the way, DOM0 style event listerens (`.foo = function(...)` can only by removed by setting the same property to something else like `null`.